# How to create a map from DataFrame and convert it to json string

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, gson, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to get a map of columnName->values from a dataframe.I tried

```
val g=dataFrame.limit(limit)
val p=g.columns.map(i=>(i,g.select(i).map(_.get(0)).collect()))
```

and

```
val g=dataFrame.limit(limit)
val p=g.columns.map(i=>(i->g.select(i).map(_.get(0)).collect()))
```

But bot gives me an Array[String,Array[Any]]
I want to get a map[String,Array[Any]]

I also tried .toMap at the end to convert array to map,

```
val g=dataFrame.limit(limit)
val p=g.columns.map(i=>(i,g.select(i).map(_.get(0)).collect())).toMap
val gson=new Gson
gson.toJson(p)
```

but this gives me json string of the form

```
{"key1":"eq_site_deductible","value1":[0.0,0.0,0.0,],"key2":"county","value2":["CLAY COUNTY","CLAY COUNTY","Mary county"]}
```

I want to get a json string of the form {"eq_site_deductible":[value array],"county":[value array]}

Answer (score -1):

If you just need the json, you don't need to convert it into map.

Below snippet can be used to write the dataframe content into a json file

```
dataFrame.write.format("json").save("result.json")
```

Or if you need the json string to be processed further in your code, you can use [dataframe.toJSON](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame) to get the RDD[String], in which String will be the json

Comment: I don't want the dataframe as individual json records. The key should column name and value should be array of values as specified in the question.